# Fluentd does not write logs in one file

Tags: logging, fluentd

I would like to ask, if someone can help with this problem? I would like the fluentd write logs to a single log file, and not create a new one.For example.

The fluentd, every 30 seconds records the logs for the whole day and keeps them in a per %Y-%M-%D folder.
The next day, he writes another file to another folder.
In the docks, I met the option of the Append file, but it does not work as it should and continues to create files. What could be  reason?

```
<source>
  @type systemd
  tag values
  path /var/log/journal
  matches [{"_SYSTEMD_UNIT":"docker.service"},{"_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "nginx.service"}]
  read_from_head true
  <storage>
    @type local
    path /var/log/fluentd/fluentd-journald-cursor.json
  </storage>
  @label @INPUT
</source>

<label @INPUT>
  <match values>
    @type rewrite_tag_filter
    remove_tag_prefix values
   <rule>
     key        CONTAINER_NAME
     pattern    /(.*)/
     tag        $1
   </rule>
   <rule>
     key        _COMM
     pattern    /(.*)/
     tag        $1
   </rule>
   @label @OUTPUT
  </match>
</label>

<label @OUTPUT>
 <match **>
  @type file
  path "/var/log/fluentd/host-#{Socket.gethostname}-${tag}/%Y-%m-%d/"
  format json
  time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H%M%S
  <buffer tag,time>
    @type file
    path /var/log/fluentd/logs/ 
    timekey 10S 
    timekey_wait 20S
    chunk_limit_size 256m
  </buffer>
  append true
 </match>
</label>
```

```
sudo ls -la /var/log/fluentd/host-node1-node1/2022-05-04/

-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 4300 May  4 09:24 .20220504085450.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:24 .20220504085500.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:24 .20220504085510.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:24 .20220504085520.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:24 .20220504085530.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085540.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085550.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085600.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085610.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085620.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085630.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085640.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085650.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 7740 May  4 09:25 .20220504085700.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085710.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085720.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085730.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085740.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085750.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085800.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085810.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085820.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085830.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085840.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085850.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085900.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085910.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085920.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085930.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085940.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504085950.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504090000.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504090010.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:25 .20220504090020.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:26 .20220504090030.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:26 .20220504090040.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 7740 May  4 09:26 .20220504090050.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:26 .20220504090100.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:26 .20220504090110.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:26 .20220504090120.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:26 .20220504090130.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:26 .20220504090140.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 td-agent td-agent 8600 May  4 09:26 .20220504090150.log
```

Comment: Please add some filenames to your question. Are these the intermediate buffered files or the final output files that are being created multiple times?

Comment: Hello! I added filenames to question. It's a final output files.